# Integration of Yeoman's angular generator with backend (Rails or Sails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yeoman, sails.js

I'm planning to use Yeoman's Angular generator and some backend (current options are Sails or Rails).

My main concern right now is to come up with a decent integration between the front-end and back-end, so I have a few points that confuse me a bit:

- Yeoman's build process generates a dist folder. How can I integate the build process (and point to it from the backend) when my backend is set at production?
- I'll have to run startup process for both the backend and frontend, which looks ugly. Also get them running in same port.
- If I keep the frontend and the backend on different projects, that may clean things a bit, but what is going to be my worflow by working on two different projects? Maybe I could include the front-end project as a git package on my backend public folder?

Based on your experience, what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at this.
http://www.emmanueloga.com/2013/07/23/Using-AngularJS-with-a-Rails-backend.html